# Why don't worked ? Onclick javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

Hey guys why don't worked ? when I click button then rewrite the text to the next array element.
This:

```
<button onclick="elfogadas()" id="elfog">Elfogadom</button>
```

Function:

```
function elfogadas() {';
    echo '$("#ititle").html("' . $idea_title[$random_values[$vid]] . '"); 
}
</script>';
```

Coded in PHP
The array elements are OK
But only 1x edit the text.

This is why?

I hope help.

(Sorry bad english)

Update:

declared random_values array

```
$random_values = array();
for($i = 0; $i <= $all_ideas-1; $i++){
$random = rand(1, $all_ideas);
while(in_array($random, $random_values)) $random = rand(1, $all_ideas);
    $random_values[] = $random;
}
```

Get first

```
echo '<center><h4 id="ititle" style="color: white;">' . $idea_title[$random_values[$vid]] . '</h4>
            <hr style="border: 1px solid white;">
            <font id="istyle" style="color: white;">' . $idea_style[$random_values[$vid]] . '</font><br>
            <textarea id="itext" style="height: 300px; width: 410px;" name="bbcode_field">' . $idea_text[$random_values[$vid]] . '</textarea><br>
            <font id="icreatedb" style="color: white;">Ötlet kitalálója: ' . $idea_created[$random_values[$vid]] . '</font><br>
            <table width="100%" style="margin-top: 25px; margin-bottom: 25px;"><tr width="100%"><center>
            <td width="50%"><center><button onclick="elfogadas()">Elfogadom</button></center></td>
            <td width="50%"><center><button onclick="elutasit()">Elutasítom</button></center></td></center>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </center>';
```

Edit use with onclick function

```
$conn->close();
?>
<script>
function elfogadas() {
<?php $vid++; ?>
$("#ititle").html("<?php echo $idea_title[$random_values[$vid]]; ?>"); 
return 1;
}
</script>
```

My problem just once edit the following items are not displayed.
Sorry sorry very bad english.

Comment: javascript onclick can only call javascript functions not php functions. To call a php function you'd have to do an ajax call to a php page, and either make that page always call that function or send some parameter and use if-logic to figure out what php function to call

Comment: `echo` in a `JavaScript` function?

Answer (score 0):

From what you said i am assumming that you wrote the js function from php, here is the correct code

```
function elfogadas() {
    $("#ititle").html("<?php $vid++;echo $idea_title[$random_values[$vid]]; ?>"); 
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: $vid++; where to paste ?

Comment: @TJayceon please update the code so i can help you better :)

Comment: @TJayceon updated the answer from what i can make of it, if it helps please accept the answer ;)

Comment: I am still not clear on the question.... Are there multiple html elements and you want each calling a separate js function ? It would help if you can be a little specific on the use-case of your situation

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix JavaScript and PHP in that way. PHP is server side scripting language that is launched only once when your browser send request.

If you want to get random value from PHP array, you need to pass this array to JavaScript and then use javascript's random() method or you can use AJAX to make calls to server.